# Connect to GCP datalab results in error 255

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab, google-cloud-sdk

I can create a datalab VM on the command line fine (e.g. datalab create datalabvm-5), and this will open a datalab session on port 8081. However, when I try to re-connect to the same vm using command "datalab connect datalabvm-5", I get the following error:

ssh: connect to host 35.188.103.167 port 22: Operation timed out

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/local/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
Connection broken
Attempting to reconnect...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That's usually caused by the firewall rules in your project.

The `datalab create` command adds a firewall rule to your project named `datalab-network-allow-ssh`.

The first thing you should do is to check the current firewall rules (you can see them in the Cloud Console) to make sure that rule is still there.

Comment: Thanks for the response. All the firewall rules are there, but tbh i'm not sure what to look for - 35.188.103.167 is definitely listed. Any advice would be great!

Comment: I updated to the latest release and all seems to be working now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case this error was solved by specifying  the zone in the datalab  command line

When I created the datalab  vm:

```
datalab create <my-vm-name>
```

I selected: "[27] us-central1-a" as zone

Then, in order to connect again, I use following command:

```
datalab connect --zone us-central1-a <my-vm-name>
```

Without specifying the --zone parameter, I get the error you mentioned.